# .filter() method to extract data that doesn’t have null

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, filter, methods

I am trying to filter out object values into a variable that do not have values of ‘null’ within the ‘releaseYear’ property because I only want movies listed on the page that have a year to go along with the title and image. What am I doing wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

SO is wanting me to add more text so..I have javascript, html, css below.

JS

```
// VARIABLE LIBRARY
let searchEl = document.querySelector('#search')
let movieCardBoxEl = document.querySelector('#movieCardBox')
// moviecard.setAttrbiute style and add borders and stuff
let movieCardEl = document.querySelector('#movieCard')
let movieTitleEl = document.querySelector('#movieTitle')

// SEARCH FLICK
searchEl.addEventListener('click', () => {
  let inputEl = document.querySelector('#input')

  const url = `https://moviesdatabase.p.rapidapi.com/titles/search/keyword/${inputEl.value}?info=base_info`;

  const options = {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      'X-RapidAPI-Key': '4165450571mshe599f8c8e4e26f2p132bb2jsn0e744e67b61b',
      'X-RapidAPI-Host': 'moviesdatabase.p.rapidapi.com'
    }
  };

  fetch(url, options)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
      console.log('data: ', data);

      let movieData = data.results.filter(obj => {
        for (let key in obj) {
          if (obj[key].releaseYear === null) {
            return false
          } else {
            return true
          }
        } 
      })
      console.log('movieData: ', movieData);

      // mapping over movies array to render movie titles as cards
      movieCardBoxEl.innerHTML = movieData.map((movie) => {
        console.log(movie)
        return `
          <div class="movie-cards">
            <h2>${movie.titleText.text}</h2>
            <p>${movie?.releaseYear?.year || ""}</p>
            <img class="movie-img" src="${movie?.primaryImage?.url || ""}" alt="" srcset="">
          </div>  
        `

      }).join('')
    })
    .catch(err => console.error('error:' + err));
})
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Movies</title>
</head>
<body>






  <header>
    <div>
      <h1>Movies</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="search-input-box">
      <input id="input" type="text">
      <button id="search">Search</button>
    </div>
  </header>
  
  <section id="movieCardBox" class="movie-card-box">
    <!-- MOVIE CARD RENDERS -->
  </section>





  <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border: 1px red solid; 
}

header h1 {
  margin: 0;
}

header input {
  margin: 0 10px 0 0;
}

header .search-input-box {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  /* border: 1px red solid; */

}

.movie-card-box {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border: 1px red solid; 
  margin: 20px 0 0 0;
  padding: 10px;
}

.movie-cards {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px red solid;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 5px 0 5px 0;
}

h2 {
  border: 1px solid red; 
  margin: 10px 10px 0 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.movie-title {
  border: 1px solid red; 
}

.movie-img {
  float: left;
  width:  150px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0 0 10px 0;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you only want to filter out the null value? what about the undefined value?

If yes, below filtering logic should be enough:

```js
// mock data
const data = {
  results: [{
      releaseYear: '2021'
    },
    {
      releaseYear: null // This data will be filtered out
    },
    {
      releaseYear: '2023'
    }
  ]
}

let movieData = data.results.filter(obj => obj.releaseYear !== null)

console.log(movieData);
```

Comment: Correct, if the filter method while iterating through every object property of 'releaseYear' is not equal to 'null' then the assigned array to the filter method should be only be holding all objects that has a value for 'releaseYear'. 

I tried your method, but is not working. Out of curiosity, were you able to render movies and make it work?